# IntelliJ javascript debugger of Angular app with Chrome on specific profile

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, debugging, intellij-idea, javascript-debugger

I'm using IntelliJ as debugger of my Angular application. I've followed steps similar to the ones described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/angular.html#angular_running_and_debugging_run). The debugger is set up and works perfectly by starting the debugging session using the "Angular Application" run configuration as officially described in the provided link.

My problem is that during the debugging session, the Google Chrome window that opens does not seem to use ay of my Chrome profiles. I need to instruct IntelliJ to open Chrome browser in a specific profile, in order to be able to use some of my Chrome's extensions while debugging the Angular application.

Does any one know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea uses Chrome protocol with `--remote-debugging-port` option for javascript debugging. Debug session is started in a new window and using new, fresh custom Chrome profile to make sure that no instances that use the same user data are running - this is required as a port for debugging can't be opened after browser is started.

You can modify Chrome settings in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers** to launch Chrome with your own user data (settings, extensions, etc.) - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-javascript-debugger.html#ws_js_debug_default_chrome_user_data.
But, if you do this, always make sure that Chrome is not already running with your user data before starting a debugging session, it won't work otherwise.
Note also that it has to be a path to Chrome [user data folder](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3202.58/docs/user_data_dir.md), not profile. If you are using a non-default profile, try adding `--profile-directory="<Your Profile name>"` option to **Command line options:** field

Comment: That was indeed the solution I was looking for! It works as expected.